# LSTM predict for rare event

Tags: lstm, recurrent-neural-network

I have data frame with 2 columns:Date, Volume. I want to predict volumn in rare event by Date. Can you give me an example or suggestion? Thank all

Updated: I use Autoencoder for predict volume and it fits perfect. But i wonder the result. Any suggestion?

```
   # define model
     model = Sequential()
     model.add(LSTM(128, activation='relu', input_shape=(7,1), 
     return_sequences=True))
     model.add(LSTM(64, activation='relu', return_sequences=False))
     model.add(RepeatVector(1))
     model.add(LSTM(64, activation='relu', return_sequences=True))
     model.add(LSTM(128, activation='relu', return_sequences=True))
     model.add(TimeDistributed(Dense(1)))
     model.compile(optimizer='adam', loss='mse')
     model.summary()
     # fit model
     model.fit(x_train, x_train, epochs=100, batch_size=5, verbose=0
```

Data and result here:
[enter link description here](https://onedrive.live.com/Edit.aspx?resid=437553259C0D8140!279&wd=cpe)

Comment: Please share in your questions an additional information that can help other users understand the problem. What have you already tried? Do you have a working code or an example definition of a "rare event"?

Comment: @TimMironov I updated some informations